¿Cómo manejar el desbalance de clases en un problema de clasificación con aprendizaje automático?
Estoy trabajando en un problema de clasificación con aprendizaje automático donde tengo un desbalance significativo entre las clases. Por ejemplo, tengo una clase positiva con solo el 10% de las muestras y una clase negativa con el 90% restante. ¿Cuáles son las estrategias recomendadas para abordar este desbalance y mejorar el rendimiento de mi modelo? ¿Cómo puedo ajustar los parámetros del modelo o utilizar técnicas específicas para lidiar con esta situación?

Tal y como está planteada la pregunta parece no ajustarse bien al contenido/formato del sitio. Parece un poco amplia y buscando opiniones (y no termino de tener claro si es sobre programación o no). Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla), y luego edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles y, a ser posible, el código que estés utilizando.


Re-muestreo de datos:


Submuestreo (undersampling): debes eliminar aleatoriamente muestras de la clase mayoritaria para igualar el número de muestras de la clase minoritaria.

Sobremuestreo (oversampling): debes replicar aleatoriamente muestras de la clase minoritaria para igualar el número de muestras de la clase mayoritaria. Algunas técnicas comunes son SMOTE (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique) y ADASYN (Adaptive Synthetic Sampling).

Métodos combinados: puedes utilizar una combinación de submuestreo y sobremuestreo para equilibrar las clases. Por ejemplo, puedes submuestrear la clase mayoritaria y luego aplicar SMOTE a la clase minoritaria.



Exploración de hiperparámetros:

Puedes realizar una búsqueda de hiperparámetros para encontrar la combinación óptima que maximice el rendimiento de tu modelo en el conjunto de datos desbalanceado.
